# Function explode not working with "+" character

Tags: php

I'm creating form in PHP for reset User password.
When user send request for reset it send link to the Mail for reset password.
In the link is `domain.com/index.php?link=reset-password&code=1_Xzpq+/F64xwZ/oQ/U4TkTQ==`

1 = User_id
Xzpq.. = User password hash (Salted)

I need explode UserID and PasswordHash to the variables

My code:

```
function isValidPasswordResetToken($string) {
    global $sqlConnect;
    //$string_exp = explode('_', $string);
    list($user_id, $password) = explode('_', $string);
    //$user_id    = $string_exp[0];
    //$password   = $string_exp[1];
    if (empty($user_id) or !is_numeric($user_id) or $user_id < 1) {
        return false;
    }
    if (empty($password)) {
        return false;
    }
    $query = mysqli_query($sqlConnect, " SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM " . USERS . " WHERE `user_id` = {$user_id} AND `password` = '{$password}' AND `active` = '1' ");
    return (Sql_Result($query, 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}
```

It works good, BUT.. When PasswordHash is like `Xzpq+/F64xwZ/oQ/U4TkTQ==` (in Hash is '+' character) it not working..
When PasswordHash is `m7c7Tn67QpI2eI1jLdqOEg==` it works without problem..

It is a chance to do this some other way, which would support all the characters? Or what am I doing wrong?

Thank you for every answer.

Comment: you're open to SQL injection and should address this immediately

Comment: Am I the only one thinking that exposing passwords (regardless of whether they are hashed or not) is bad?

Comment: I think [How to use password_hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279321/how-to-use-password-hash) is worth a read.

Comment: @maio290 This is not script for Encrypt password. This is only script for pick ID+Password_hash from DB for identify user for password reset.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `+` is used by browsers to replace spaces in the URL.

You just need to encode it first, and decode when you want to process it.

```
<?php

$x = urlencode('Xzpq+/F64xwZ/oQ/U4TkTQ==');
echo $x . "\n";
echo urldecode($x);
```

Output:

```
Xzpq%2B%2FF64xwZ%2FoQ%2FU4TkTQ%3D%3D 
Xzpq+/F64xwZ/oQ/U4TkTQ==
```

See it here https://3v4l.org/QUeXT

Comment: Thanks for fast solution! :) Finally. It works! Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: Of course decoding is done by the server for values passed in via $_GET, so there's rarely a need for `urldecode()`